# MongoDB Indexing many categories in each product, data modeling

Tags: mongodb, database-design, relational-database

Moving from a MySQL database to MongoDB, I have to replicate this feature in a product catalog:

1. Each product has multiple categories
2. Each category has a name, id and position of the product in each category
3. Performance when querying for products by category, sorting by category position or other fields such as price and tags

This is an example of a model I came up with

```
{
   ...
   categories: [
       {
           name: 'Clothing',
           category_id: 1,
           position: 0
       },
       {
           name: 'Bottoms',
           category_id: 2,
           position: 2
       },
       {
           name: 'Jeans',
           category_id: 5,
           position: 0
       }
   ]
}
```

Should I separate the name, category_id and position into different top level fields for indexing?

Comment: couldn't get what the position field stands for?

Comment: @hevi The position field is for sorting the product within the category. Eg. In the Bottoms category, we sort it by position DESC using the value 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your document example provided seems it's impossible to perform search by category with efficient indexing by this category position

Surely, you can index "position", "name" and run query

```
db.coll.find({"categories.name": "Jeans"}).sort({"categories.position": -1})
```

But it wouldn't be proper sorting by desired category.

I'd suggest having document part:

```
{
  ...
  "categories": ["Clothing", "Bottoms", "Jeans"],
  "positions": {
    "Clothing": 0,
    "Bottoms": 2,
    "Jeans": 0
  }
}
```

Then you will be able to run query

```
db.coll.find({categories: "Jeans"}).sort({"positions.Jeans": -1})
```